# Apply jQuery to every instance of foreach loop but only operating on the element clicked upon

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I am looking to apply jQuery to every instance of foreach loop but only operating on the element clicked upon.

The php foreach loop is below:

```
@foreach ($entries as $entry)
                    <?php $row = DB::table('workout_trainings')->where('date', $entry->format('Y-m-d'))->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->count(); ?>
                    <tr style="border-top: 2px solid black;">
                        <th rowspan={{$row}}><p>{{ $entry->format('l- d/m/Y') }}</p>
                            <button class="btn btn-default" id="goals_btn">Goals</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default" id="logs_btn">Log Workout</button>
                        </th>
                        <?php $ws = DB::table('workout_trainings')->where('date', $entry->format('Y-m-d'))->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get(); ?>
                         @foreach ($ws as $w)
                        <td>{{$w->exercise}}</td>
                        <td>{{$w->weight}}</td>
                        <td>{{$w->sets}}</td>
                        <td>{{$w->reps}}</td>
                    </tr>

                @endforeach
                <tr id="goals">
                    <td colspan='5'>.</td>
                </tr>     
                <tr id="logs">
                    <td colspan='5'>.</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>    
        </table>         
    <?php echo $entries->setPath('')->render(); ?>
```

The jQuery I have is simply:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#goals").css("display","none");
    $("#goals_btn").click(function(){
        $("#goals").toggle(200);
    });
});
```

Which obviously works for the top item.

**UPDATE**

Slide now works however only on elements with less than two rows filled.[image: Wednesday doesn't work but Thursday and Friday do in this example]

Wednesday doesn't work but Thursday and Friday do in this example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#goals").css("display","none");
    $("#goals_btn").click(function(){
        $(this).find("#goals").toggle(200);  // use this to point clicked instance
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello @A.t. that works perfectly, however it raises another issue that I have explained in an update above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the HTML your PHP code is generating as you will have lots of elements with the same `id` attribute which is invalid; they must be unique within the document. A class would seem more appropriate in this case.

From there you can use the `this` keyword to reference the element that raised the event and traverse the DOM to find the related `tr.goals`. Try this:

```
.goals {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".goals_btn").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').next('.goals').toggle(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly @Rory McCrossan, it has however shown another issue with regards to is only working on rows with less than two items. I gather this is a HTML table issue now.